# How do you get a month name from an integer value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

How do you get a month name from an integer value?

e.g. 7 is July

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
// using the current culture - returns "July" for me
string x = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(7);

// using a specific culture - returns "juillet"
string y = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR").DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(7);
```

Comment: This is the best approach. But watch out for cultures that use a different calendar...

Answer (score 3):

Using a custom format string:

```
string name = new DateTime(2010,7,1).ToString("MMMM");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the DateTime object's ToString() method.  "MMMM" is the long month.  "MMM" is a short month code like Aug for August.  The nice thing is this way, you can deal with i18n issues too if you need to.

```
var monthID = 7;
var monthName = new DateTime(2000, monthID, 1).ToString("MMMM");
Console.WriteLine(monthName);
```

Comment: Huh... there wasn't a single answer when I started typing mine...  well, at least we're all in agreement.

Answer (score 1):

```
  private static string GetMonthName(int month, bool abbrev)

  {

      DateTime date = new DateTime(1900, month, 1);

      if (abbrev) return date.ToString("MMM");

      return date.ToString("MMMM");

  }
```

Comment: `return new DateTime(1900, month, 1).ToString(abbrev ? "MMM" : "MMMM");` would do all that with less code.

Answer (score -3):

Dude!!

just have an string array containing names of 12 months, and names[7] is it.

Comment: No, that would give you "August".

Comment: And besides, why reinvent the wheel? `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames[7]` does indeed give me "August".